# How to type function taking an enum

Tags: typescript, enums, type-inference, typescript-generics

Given some `enum MyEnum {ONE, TWO}`, I wanted to write a function called like

```
useMyFun(MyEnum, MyEnum.ONE);
```

and I failed to type it properly. Now I have something like the following

```
type StringKeyOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;
type EnumNumber<E> = Record<StringKeyOf<E>, number>;
function useMyFun<E extends EnumNumber<E>, V extends number=number> (
    anEnum: E,
    initialState: number) : {value: V, setValue: (v: V) => void}
{
    const [value, setValue] = useState<V>(initialState as V);
    //.... more stuff using both arguments omitted    
    return {value, setValue};
}
```

It's a react-hook, but this doesn't matter as all you need to compile it is a dummy

```
function useState<V>(initialState: V) {
    const result: [V, (v: V) => void] = [initialState, v => { }];
    return result;
}
```

It works (using the current typescript version), but it allows me to call `useMyFun(MyEnum, -1)` as well, which is wrong. Note that I only care about enums like above, i.e., enums with default numerical values, no specified values and no `const` modifier.

*I also need that the return type has `value: MyEnum` rather than `number`.

---

I know that the runtime value of `MyEnum` is `{0: 'ONE', 1: 'TWO', ONE: '0', TWO: '1'}` which means that the above typing is actually wrong. However, this was the only way how to get the first argument compile. The second argument when dealing with `MyEnum` should actually be `0 | 1`, but I can't get it working.

I really need both the enum object and the value in the function. *Can someone get the types right?*

Comment: Are you trying to get the function's second argument to only allow a specific value from the enum?

Comment: How invested are you in using enums?

Comment: @JacquesジャックNo, I need to provide all enum values in the result to populate a select (not shown above).

Comment: @rob3c Here, enums are best as unlike `'ONE' | 'TWO'`, they provide the list of all values, which is what I need.

Comment: @maaartinus I disagree they’re best here, as you’ve already  hit a significant limitation in parameter value restriction in your question. However, it seems you’ve already pre-decided what’s best, so I’ll leave you to it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Related question you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591789/enum-typescript-return-specific-value#answer-70592714)

There is another one approach to figure out whether initial value is valid or not.

As you already know, TS might treat `enum` as a `number` or as an object or `typeof enum`. In the similar way typescript treats `classes`.

We need some how to obtain numerical keys of `enum`.

Let's try to iterate through `enum` keys:

```js
enum MyEnum {
    ONE,
    TWO
}

type Enumerate<Enum extends number | string> = keyof {
    [Prop in Enum]: Prop
}

// non generic version 
type Keys = keyof typeof MyEnum
type Enumerate2 = keyof {
    [Prop in Keys]: Prop
}


type Result = Enumerate<MyEnum> // MyEnum, not good
```

It does not work, because TS is smart enought to figure out that we are iterating over enum keys. Hence we are getting `MyEnum` instead of `0 | 1`.

We can wrap `Prop` key into a string to cheat typescript.

```js
enum MyEnum {
    ONE,
    TWO
}

type Enumerate<Enum extends number | string> = keyof {
    [Prop in `${Enum}`]: Prop
}

type Result = Enumerate<MyEnum> // "0" | "1"
```

Much better now. But it is still not what we want. It is impossible to extract number from a string in current version of typescript in generic way.

But we always can compare string to number which is wrapped in string during the comparison.
I mean something like that: `"0" extends` ${number} ? ...`
Above code is perfectly valid.

```js
enum MyEnum {
    ONE,
    TWO
}

type Enumerate<Enum extends number | string> = keyof {
    [Prop in `${Enum}`]: Prop
}

type Result = Enumerate<MyEnum> // "0" | "1"


type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type IsKeyValid<InitialValue extends number, Enum extends Record<string | number, string | number>> =
    `${InitialValue}` extends Enumerate<Values<Enum>> ? InitialValue : never

function useMyFun<
    Enum extends Record<string | number, string | number>,
    InitialValue extends number,
    >(anEnum: Enum, initialState: IsKeyValid<InitialValue, Enum>) { }

useMyFun(MyEnum, MyEnum.ONE) // ok
useMyFun(MyEnum, 0) // ok

useMyFun(MyEnum, -1) // error
useMyFun(MyEnum, NaN) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKCpqB5AcggGgywBUB1bNAXzTQBc4AHYKJSYAJwEM7gAeNtGAAPXiAAmAZyjIARpygAfKJLocAliADmAPigBeKAGtgcAPYAzKOixQA2gAUOZxlE1QABgBIUgqh4BdAC4oJxdqWgZmKAAlYEkwABs6A1ZkTh5+eEE9AHpcqAAiAAZCpSKARkLaeiYWADUuRLB4vhI9QxI7E3MrEgDIuqgASUkAaVNGxPVxPmGQdTp1JqmWqBExKRlIeQ4CNMh10VAtuIBjMw5Z1Q1tcrlOfZvNLXudzh0O4kxvFHnF5aJVbAfxHTbSQQZXh8YGSATIT5QAD8IwWSxWTTWIRAwAAbpxaBYwCAzkszCAoGBJMB4AAxYl8b4HITHCTSc6Xa5qF5vCC7J7cu7KB4cHREWz-dFAzEsDYnaQi8VYHQACi4IEEIUE+00AKaAGU6JkQqMJnApjM5mjAcD9jkAJTWKA0NBUmlwekgFXZZD7H2QAB0eAQjvyUDMRld1LpxO9iF9UGKoYKEdobpjXv9EH2AFoKsn1hxnBwo+7PXHtVBcFxcAXOMWgA)

`Enum` - is infered type of enum

`InitialValue` - is infered type of second argument.

`IsKeyValid` - is an utility type which checks whether wrapped into string `InitialValue` is equal to allowed enum keys or not. If it equal - return `InitialValue`, otherwise return `never`

P.S. Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184199/typescript-is-not-throwing-errors-when-invalid-value-passed-to-the-props/70185030#70185030) with React component props

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying that I highly advise against doing this, but for the sake of fun, here's a hack to get the behavior you're looking for. This solution effectively makes the enum's values into an [opaque type](https://evertpot.com/opaque-ts-types/).

```
enum _MyEnum {
  ONE,
  TWO,
}

declare const __brand: unique symbol;

type MyEnum = {
  [K in keyof typeof _MyEnum]: (typeof _MyEnum)[K] & {
    readonly [__brand]: never;
  };
};

const MyEnum: MyEnum = _MyEnum as any;

type StringKeyOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;
type EnumNumber<E> = Record<StringKeyOf<E>, number>;

function useMyFun<E extends EnumNumber<E>, V extends E[keyof E]>(
  anEnum: E,
  initialState: V
): { value: V; setValue: (v: V) => void } {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<V>(initialState as V);
  //.... more stuff using both arguments omitted
  MyEnum.ONE.toFixed;
  MyEnum.ONE;
  return { value, setValue };
}

useMyFun(MyEnum, MyEnum.ONE);
useMyFun(MyEnum, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

your way have an question.When Enum has '0',it can pass 0 to the function.

```
type EnumToNumber<T extends number, arr extends number[] = []>
    = `${T}` extends `-${infer N}` ? never :
    T extends arr['length'] ? arr['length']
    : EnumToNumber<T, [...arr, 1]>

type SafeEnum<T extends Record<string | number, string | number>,
    >
    = {
        [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends number ? EnumToNumber<T[key]> : `${T[key]}`
    }[keyof T]
```

it can work with string enum.but i don't find a way to transform negative number string literal to negative number literal

```
enum E{
  A=0,
  B=1,
  C='0'
}
type E=SafeEnum<typeof E> //0,1,'0'
```