# Typescript: enum generic Type as parameter to function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

i have a function which takes two parameters one is a key and other is an enum type.  I am trying to generalize this function with strong typing to take any enum type and return the value:

```
export const getStatus = <T>(key: string, statEnum: any): string => {
 return statEnum(key);
}
```

function call:

```
console.log(getStatus<SVC_A>('AUTH_122', SVC_A));
```

This above function works with paramater typed as any `statEnum: any` but if I change it to `statEnum: typeof T`  it throws an error message

> T only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Parameter typing works if I add in a variable

```
type supportedEnums = typeof SVC_A | typeof SVC_B
export const getStatus = <T>(key: string, statEnum: supportedEnums): string => {
 return statEnum(key);
}
```

curious to understand, why it works with supportedEnums type but when it's added as `typeof T` it doesn't.

i also tried it as

```
export const getStatus = <T>(key: string, statEnum: T): string => {
 return statEnum(key);
}
```

updated function parameter type to T `statEnum: T` it thorws error message while calling the function
function call:

```
console.log(getStatus<SVC_A>('AUTH_122', SVC_A));
```

> Argument of type 'typeof SVC_A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SVC_A'

Is there a possibility to define an enum as a parameter and typesafe?

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: https://playcode.io/908185

Comment: once you do any changes(placing semicolon) in the above link, it will show the error message "Argument of type 'typeof SVC_A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SVC_A'" .   In the playground parameter type is set to type T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you dont need to use explicit generic parameter.
Consider this example:

```js
enum SVC_A {
    INVALID = 'INVALID',
    YENNA = 'YENNA',
    AUTH_122 = 'AUTH FAILED',
}

type PseudoEnum = Record<string | number, string | number>


function getStatus<Enum extends PseudoEnum, Key extends keyof Enum>(statEnum: Enum, key: Key) {
    return statEnum[key];
};

const foo = getStatus(SVC_A, 'YENNA') // SVC_A.YENNA
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQ8lYW)
List of related questions:

- [How to type function taking an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268023/how-to-type-function-taking-an-enum#answer-69465829)
- [Enum typescript return specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591789/enum-typescript-return-specific-value/70592714#70592714)

[Here](https://catchts.com/safe-enums) you can find my article with more context and explanation